# Android KeyboardView in Fragment not being resized

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I am using a Fragment class in a TabHost.  This fragment inflates a KeyboardView like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null)
            return null;
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_keyboard, container, false);
```

This works fine the first time `onCreateView()` is invoked (when the application loads).  However, subsequent screen rotates (runtime configuration changes) don't re-size the KeyboardView to landscape/portrait properly:

[image]   [image]

**main_keyboard.xml** You can see the KeyboardView being referenced at the bottom:
`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kbd_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingRight="10dip"
                android:text="@string/keyboard_type" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kbd_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/kbd_header"
                android:text="@string/russian"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnRussian"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/russian_keyboard"
            android:src="@drawable/russia" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEnglish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/english_keyboard"
            android:src="@drawable/america"
             />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnCombined"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/combined"
            android:src="@drawable/combined" />

    </LinearLayout>

<com.eazyigz.RussiaMediaSearch.CustomKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="0px"
    android:padding="0px" >
</com.eazyigz.RussiaMediaSearch.CustomKeyboardView>
```

Does anybody have ideas on how to make the KeyboardView resize correctly?

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I was using:
 `if (savedInstanceState != null)` in **onCreateView**, and wasn't creating a new Keyboard object every time the screen rotated.  So that's why the keyboard didn't resize. To resolve this, I needed to run code like this every time:

```
mKeyboard = new Keyboard(getActivity(), R.xml.keyboard);
```